# Phaser: destroying text after a fixed number of seconds

Tags: javascript, html, phaser-framework

I'm using the following function in Phaser to create floating instructions that disappear after the first 5 seconds. This function is called from inside the `create` function.

```
setupText: function () {
  this.instructions = this.add.text( 510, 600, 
    'Use Arrow Keys to Move, Press Z to Fire\nClicking does both', 
    {font: '20px monospace', fill: '#fff', align: 'center'}
  );
  this.instructions.anchor.setTo(0.5, 0.5);
  this.time.events.add(5000, this.instructions.destroy, this);
},
```

It quickly became obvious that the timed event isn't what I'm supposed to use here, because after five seconds it causes the whole game to become unresponsive.

Being a complete beginner, I searched around for the correct way to implement such events, but I couldn't find anything.

The tutorial I'm following creates a variable holding the number of seconds the message should remain for, and then calls from `update` a function that destroys the text if the time limit has been reached. This seems like a bad approach to me because the checking function is called over and over from `update` even though it's only needed for the first 5 seconds.

So I'm looking for help on the best way to do this, and also an explanation why my code caused the entire game to stop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you call this:

```
this.time.events.add(5000, this.instructions.destroy, this);
```

It calls the `destroy` function on the `this` object, which is probably your game.

To fix that, pass `this.instructions` instead.

```
this.time.events.add(5000, this.instructions.destroy, this.instructions);
```

Comment: I see, that fixes it. `this` is indeed my game. Though I'm curious why it should call `destroy` on `this` when the function to be called is a member of `this.instructions`.

Comment: @aakashjain Javascript this *is* confusing, see [this article](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html). Basically, the `this.instructions.destroy` function is not 'bound' to the `this.instructions` object. It's just a function, that usually has a `this` value of `this.instructions`.